# How to move an array of embedded docs up to parent and change key/value with aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a set of documents, each containing an array of (simple) documents. I'd like to use the aggregation pipeline to move the embedded documents ("fruits") up to the parent as shown in the below example. Note that the "name" value becomes the key in the parent document.

I've taken a look at Mongo's aggregation framework (specifically `$project`, `$replaceRoot`, `$arrayToObject`) but I've not made any progress.

I'd like to convert this

```
{
    "_id" : 3258,
    "fruits" : [
        {
            "name" : "apple",
            "quantity" : 2
        },
        {
            "name" : "banana",
            "quantity" : 86
        },
        {
            "name" : "orange",
            "quantity" : 4
        },
        {
            "name" : "pineapple",
            "quantity" : 28
        },
        {
            "name" : "strawberry",
            "quantity" : 193
        }
    ]
}
```

to this

```
{
    "_id" : 3258,
    "apple" : 2,
    "banana" : 86,
    "orange" : 4,
    "pineapple" : 28,
    "strawberry": 193
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) and [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/index.html) to create a new document root which contains both `_id` and other fields. You also can run [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) to transform an array into single document, try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                    { _id: "$_id" },
                    { $arrayToObject: { $map: { input: "$fruits", in: [ "$$this.name", "$$this.quantity" ] } } }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_HrZ1G3uhoO)